# How to create a dynamic amount of labels to fit with the data in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have three data sets which potentially have different amounts of data in them for example

a:`[1,2,3,4]`

b:`[2.5,2.3]`

c:`[4.5,4.6,4.7]`

I am currently deploying the chart like this:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("0"), {
  "type": "line",
  "data": {
    labels: new Array(a.length),
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Face Localisation',
      data: a,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#bc2122',
      fill: false
    }, {
      label: 'Feature Extractor',
      data: b,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#EEC446',
      fill: false
    }, {
      label: 'Classifier',
      data: c,
      borderWidth: 2,
      borderColor: '#67A062',
      fill: false
    }, ]
  },
  "options": {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        display: false
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Seconds'
        }
      }]
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      }
    } // remove data points
  }
});
```

Where labels is just `new Array(a.length)` to fill out the length of `a` (I will always know that `a` has the most amount of data points) as I do not care at all about the x-axis. This turns out like this (different data but same idea):

[image]

notice how the red line finishes earlier because it has less data points. I want this to finish at the end like all the rest. Is that possible?

Comment: At the end as in to the right and at the bottom? If so then just populate the rest of the array values with 0's or whatever you want. In the end all your arrays should be the same length. If yellow has length of 20 and red has length of 15, add 5 zeros to red.

Comment: @Matt no as in dragged across. imagine that the x cordinates mean nothing. If I did each `dataset` on there own `canvas` this would work well but I want them to be together.

Comment: Ok. But the x coordinates do mean something because you want them "together". If you did it in each own canvas it works because the canvas goes to the longest length of an array. If you want it to go straight right copy the last index of the array for x number of times to go straight across. If you don't want to add to the red array, make the yellow line array as long as the red line array.

Comment: Damn. Okay that is annoying. Thanks for getting back to me.